# Regex extract in Mule

Tags: regex, mule, mule-studio, dataweave

I am trying to extract the value between the comma's using regex expression in mule, but it returns null. Whereas this regex works if I try here https://regex101.com/

Mule is not allowing the regex first of all, it is expecting to escape ','

```
<logger message="Regex #[regex('(?&lt;=\,)(.*?)(?=\,)')]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Whereas the following returns null, if I try to escape ',' like '\,'

```
<logger message="Regex #[regex('(?&lt;=\\,)(.*?)(?=\\,)')]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

> Sample data: 06-28-2016-15:14:57,AMsySZYGi51CLhhsUhJDq0Nndcav,5128617

Any thoughts ? Or is there any other way to extract without using regex ?

Comment: You want to extract this 'AMsySZYGi51CLhhsUhJDq0Nndcav' For Example?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just AMsySZYGi51CLhhsUhJDq0Nndcav

Comment: I not familier with mule if you can able to refer capure group than following regex will work for you : https://regex101.com/r/oG6yL3/2

Comment: Why do you thing mule expects you to escape the comma? What happens if you try without escaping: `<logger message="Regex #[regex('(?&lt;=,)(.*?)(?=,)')]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=(,))(.*?)(?=(,))
```

Escaping here is unnecessary.

Or another way:

```
\,\K(.*)(?=(,))
```

Comment: Problem is, in mule it throw this exception. If I use your second expression for example: [Error: illegal escape sequence: ,]
[Near : {... regex('\,\K(.*)(?=(,))') ....}]
                     ^
[Line: 1, Column: 9]

Comment: As I thought - Mule Regex does not recognize \K, like many engines.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using MEL?

```
<logger message="#[payload.split(',')[1]]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```